# Access and apply struct data to label in form

Tags: c#

I'm wondering how I can access the struct fields from:

```
namespace Metry
{
    public class StaticDataEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public StaticDataEventArgs(StaticData staticData)
        {
            this.StaticData = staticData;
        }

        public StaticData StaticData { get; private set; }
    }



    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4, CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    [Serializable]
    public struct StaticData
    {
        [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst = 15)]
        public String Track;

        public int NumberOfSessions;
        public int NumCars;
    }
}
```

And use their values inside my Form to update the text value of labels for example. I dont really understand how the scope and types work in C# yet, so with my logic I wanted to try something like this:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        StaticDataEventArgs stat = new StaticDataEventArgs();

        track_label.Text = stat.StaticData.Track;
    }

}
```

But that's obviously not how to do it. I dont even know where to begin reading to understand this.

EDIT , StaticData is being filled through a stream to shared memory:

```
public StaticData ReadStaticData()
    {
        using (var stream = staticDataMMF.CreateViewStream())
        {
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
            {
                var size = Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(StaticData));
                var bytes = reader.ReadBytes(size);
                var handle = GCHandle.Alloc(bytes, GCHandleType.Pinned);
                var data = (StaticData)Marshal.PtrToStructure(handle.AddrOfPinnedObject(), typeof(StaticData));
                handle.Free();
                return data;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where have you filled the StaticData?  You put your code into Form1() which is the form constructor.   So where is the method that fills the structure?

Comment: @jdweng I've included that part in an edit now.

Comment: @Benni These 2 lines are confusing. `StaticDataEventArgs stat = new StaticDataEventArgs();

        track_label.Text = stat.StaticData.Track;`.  Why constructor `StaticDataEventArgs` is called without instance of `StaticData`. Where from are you expecting `Track` member in `stat.StaticData.Track;`.? Are we missing something?

Comment: @MKR sorry I missed including the name change I did on the variable in StaticData. What was "Version" is actually the member "Track" in my program.

Comment: So were are you calling ReadStaticData()?

Comment: What is firing the event that contains `StaticDataEventArgs` ?